# Java: How to extract the largest name from multiple folders kept at a path into a variable where folder names are all numeric?

Tags: java

There is a directory which has many folders. The folder names are all numeric. How to extract the folder name which has the greatest value into an integer variable in java?

For example: Lets say directory `.../home/user` has following folders:

`.../home/user/19620918`

`.../home/user/19620919`

`.../home/user/19620920`

How to get `x = 19620920`, where `x` is lets say the integer variable, using the simplest and most efficient code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `Files.list()`, you can use the following approach:

```java
public static OptionalInt getMaxNumericFilename(Path path) {
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(path)) {
        return files
            .filter(Files::isDirectory)
            .map(Path::getFileName)
            .map(Path::toString)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .max();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return OptionalInt.empty();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```java
Path path = Path.of(".../home/user");

OptionalInt max = getMaxNumericFilename(path);
System.out.println(max.getAsInt());
```

If the `OptionalInt` is empty, there are no present directories. If you want to add additional resiliency, you can filter if the filename is an `int` before parsing with `Integer::parseInt` which can throw an exception.

This solution will work for filename numbers up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2.147.483.647). Consider using `long` or `BigDecimal` if required.